# Chrome extension to copy the link & URL of the page as a single line Rich Text Format hyperlink to the clipboard

Tags: chrome, clipboard, hyperlink, rtf

I'm looking for a *Chrome* extension that will copy both the URL and title of the current page to the clipboard. It should copy both the title and URL in the form of Rich Text Format. The title is the "Text to display" and the URL is the "Address". Ideally this would happen when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> without anything selected.

#### Illustrative example

If you don't understand what I mean, this is an illustrative example of exactly what I need:

Let's consider these parameters:

- Page title: Page 01 Title
- Page link: `http://www.example.com/page01.html`

Let's consider that I've pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> without anything selected. And I've went to MS Word and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. The result should be: [Page 01 Title](http://www.example.com/page01.html). As you see it's a single line *Rich Text Format* hyperlink with *Text to display:* `Page 01 Title` and *Address:* `http://www.example.com/page01.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Copy All Urls](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-all-urls/djdmadneanknadilpjiknlnanaolmbfk)

Does everything mentioned in the question:

- Powerful customization
- Copies multiple tabs' links
- Customize keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 5):

The extension [Create Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/create-link/gcmghdmnkfdbncmnmlkkglmnnhagajbm?hl=en) does exactly what you want, with the exception that you have to press an icon rather than press some keys on your keyboard.

Instructions after it is installed:

1. Click on the Icon
2. Click on the "word" HTML
3. Paste to Microsoft Word

Comment: I just saw in the Configure menu that you can also highlight text, follow the instructions above, and the highlighted text will be linked. To be technical, by default it copies either the page title or the highlighted text. If you only and always want the title of the page to be copied, you can modify the existing "HTML" option or add a new one using the title variable. The only thing I dislike about the extension is that there is usually a one second delay from the time you press the icon to the time it takes to show the options.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut would be nice as it would save tons of seconds for me!

Comment: I saw someone ask for keyboard shortcut in the reviews. Maybe you can email the developer to see if he plans to include such a feature in the future.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like none of these suggestions do what the OP is asking for: Put a rich text link in your clipboard. Instead, they put plain text in the clipboard, formatted in a variety of ways (HTML, BB, Markdown, text, etc).

I've been looking for something similar and haven't found it. For what it's worth, the best one of these "grab the title and URL" extensions that I've come across is [**TabCopy**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabcopy/micdllihgoppmejpecmkilggmaagfdmb?hl=en-US). It's nice and clean and simple, supports 8 different formats including HTML and Markdown, and supports custom formats. Even better: You run it by clicking or double-clicking an icon in the right side of the location bar (click once for this tab, twice for all tabs).

It does not, however, create rich text links like I and the OP are after.

Comment: Note that on OSX TabCopy's "Link" format _does_ copy rich text where the tab title(s) text is a hyperlink to the tab URL(s). TabCopy v3.5.

Answer (score 0):

This came out of the box with Edge browser on Windows 10, and I miss it very much. So far, the Chrome extension that came the closest is [GitHub - Leksyk/chrome-copy-link: Chrome extension to copy current page url and title as a rich text link](https://github.com/Leksyk/chrome-copy-link), however it has a couple drawbacks:

- Only pastes into Google Docs/Slides etc.
- Only pastes in a specific font size 9 smaller than the default 11

Answer (score 0):

I had been looking for example what OP describes too, specifically for Slack. I've managed to fit this into my workflow by using the Chrome extension [CopyTabTitleUrl](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copytabtitleurl/lmgbdjfoaihhgdphombpgjpaohjfeapp) from bugbugnow.net.

It allows you to copy the current tab or all your tabs into formatted Markdown to your clipboard, which Slack recognizes and asks to convert for you.

[TabCopy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabcopy/micdllihgoppmejpecmkilggmaagfdmb) is a similar Chrome Extension that allows you to do that same thing.

It probably won't fix it for your Microsoft Word use case, but for other apps might be helpful.